# how to split array into small block, and rejoin them back

Tags: python, numpy, split

I am new to python. I need to update the data in an 2D array,
first to split the array into small blocks so that the number in each location would be multiply by certain value. for example the original array will be like:

```
[[a1, b1, c1, d1,   ......]
 [a2, b2, c2, d2,   ......]
 [a3, b3, c3, d3,   ......]
 [a4, b4, c4, d4,   ......]
 [...........................]])
```

Then split into 2x2 array and multiply each of them with different value

```
[[a1(2), b1(3)]
 [a2(4), b2(5)])
```

and then rejoin them back together

```
[[a1(2), b1(3), c1(2), d1(3),   ......]
 [a2(4), b2(5), c2(4), d2(5),   ......]
 [a3(2), b3(3), c3(2), d3(3),   ......]
 [a4(4), b4(5), c4(4), d4(5),   ......]
 [...........................]])
```

is there a way to do that in python? many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NumPy` (particularly `numpy.pad()`) as:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(30).reshape(6, 5)
print(a)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
#  [ 5  6  7  8  9]
#  [10 11 12 13 14]
#  [15 16 17 18 19]
#  [20 21 22 23 24]
#  [25 26 27 28 29]]

b = np.array([[0, 1],
              [2, 3]])
print(b)
# [[0 1]
#  [2 3]]

new_a = a*np.pad(b, ((0, a.shape[0]-b.shape[0]), (0, a.shape[1]-b.shape[1])), mode = 'wrap')
print(new_a)
# [[ 0  1  0  3  0]
#  [10 18 14 24 18]
#  [ 0 11  0 13  0]
#  [30 48 34 54 38]
#  [ 0 21  0 23  0]
#  [50 78 54 84 58]]
```

If you array is not a `NumPy` array, then convert it into `NumPy` using:

```
import numpy as np
numpy_array = np.array(not_numpy_array)
```